# Two points with “identical” local geometry on Riemann Manifolds

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Let $S$ and $T$ be Riemann Manifolds of dimension $n$ and let $s$ be a point in $S$ and $t$ be a point in $T$.  Is there a way to say that the local geometry of $s$ is “identical” to the local geometry of $t$, perhaps about some symmetry?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would always be careful with the word "identical" in mathematics. In this situation, what I would say is that the local geometries of $s$ and $t$ are *isometric* is there exist open subsets $U \subset S$ and $V \subset T$, and an isometry $f : U \to V$, such that $s \in U$, $t \in V$, and $f(s)=t$. In case you don't the definition, to say that $f$ is an isometry means that $f$ is a diffeomorphism, and for every $x \in U$ and $y=f(x) \in V$ the derivative map $D_x f : T_x U \to T_y V$ is a linear isomorphism that preserves the inner products on those spaces (given by the Riemannian metrics), i.e. for each $v,w \in T_x U$ we have $\langle v,w \rangle = \langle D_x(v),D_x(w) \rangle$.

Comment: Would it be possible to categorize all possible local geometries of dimension $n$ in the same way that all local geometries of dimension $n$ can be represented by a number on the real line?

Comment: Probably you should learn some differential geometry first. Learn the curvature tensor, and sectional curvatures, and other types of curvature functions such as Ricci curvature. Learn about their their invariance under isometry. Then I think the problem will answer itself for you.

Comment: After reading your response repeatedly, it seems to me that what you described is two open sets $U$ and $V$ such that have the same geometry.  What I originally had in mind was a generalization to Gaussian Curvature, where if you have a point $x$ in $X$ and $y$ in $Y$, then the way geometry behaves at $x$ is determined by the Gaussian Curvature of that point, and geometry behaves the same at $y$ iff they have the same Gaussian Curvature.

Comment: So my thinking is now that your response is for when we want two entire patches to behave the same geometrically, but if we just want two points to behave the same, we just want an isometry between the two points.

Comment: That could be a different situation; what I wrote in my answer is the standard meaning of "local" (it has become standard because of its practical applications). But keep in mind that it is not at all clear what you mean by "an isometry between two points". Are talking about existence of an isometry between two one point metric spaces? If so, that is an entirely trivial situation which you can easily resolve. Or are you talking about something else?

Comment: When I think of curvature, I see it as a property defined at each point, not a property of an open set.  So for surfaces, two points have the same curvature if their gaussian curvature is the same.  I have read that in higher dimensions, $n^2 *(n^2 - 1)/12$ variables are required to define curvature.  I want to know when two points are identical from the perspective of these variables.

Comment: That's beginning to sound more interesting, and I would encourage you to post something like that, but you should still try to improve the formulation of a potential question. For example, on a Riemannian surface, you get a function on the surface which assigns to each point its Gaussian curvature. What more do you want you know about this class of functions?

Comment: I’m not sure I understand your question so my response may come off as nebulous.  With my current understanding, Gaussian Curvature is the main tool used to describe how geometry behaves between points on a surface.  If you know the Gaussian curvature of every point, you know how geometry behaves on the surface.  My thought process is along the lines of that the curvature of each point influences the geometry of the surface an infinitesimally small amount, and then when you get an open set of these points they form an actual geometry.

Comment: As an example, when a point $p$ has 0 curvature, there is something inherently flat about it.  It may turn out that for any $r > 0$, a geodesic circle of radius $r$ centered around $p$ may be non-isomorphic to a circle of radius $r$ on the Euclidean plane in the way you defined isometry.  However, as $r$ gets closer to 0, the two circles get more and more isometric to each other, which I am more than aware is a nonsensical statement.

Comment: In computer science, one could approximate the gaussian curvature of a surface using a triangulation of the surface, and as the maximum edge length of the triangulation approaches 0, the approximation approaches the gaussian curvature of the surface at each point.  I am wondering if, for example, Tetrahedral triangulations of 3D spaces could be used to approximate the 6 variables of curvature at each point in such a way where as the maximum edge length approaches 0, the approximations of curvature becomes the actual curvature, and could we do this for any dimension.